# Where to find host ns records in GoDaddy?

Tags: wordpress, hosting, nameservers, godaddy-api

[The hosting I bought for a client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4K1d8.png) [I did not configure anything yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFgrm.png)

Hi,

I bought the above hosting plan for a client.My client has the domain he previously bought in GoDaddy. He is asking me to give him the **host NS records**.

I'm completely new to this GoDaddy and hosting stuffs.
Please tell me where I can find the ns records for my hosting plan I bought. I don't have access to my clients' domain.

In summery, **I have a hosting plan in GoDaddy which I didn't configure yet and I want my clients' domain access** to continue with the project.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Comment: You should know your NS. You can contact their support team and ask your NS. Then, you can point your domain to that NS in order to host your domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NS records indicate which DNS server is authoritative for a domain name.

1. Sign in to your GoDaddy Domain Portfolio
2. Select three-dot icon to select domain edit options Domain Edit Options next to your domain and then select Edit DNS. You may need to scroll down to see Edit DNS.

You can find out more information from here: https://in.godaddy.com/help/add-an-ns-record-19212

Thanks